# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RoomTicketController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am receiving the 'RoomTicketController' is not a function error , got undefined on my page load.

Here are my components:
Roomticket.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.SystemSetup.roomticket',[])
        .controller('RoomTicketController',  function RoomTicketController($http, $scope, $state, $rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $mdToast, $document, $cookieStore, $mdDialog ) {
            $scope.PageTitle =" Room Ticket"
        });
})();
```

Roomticket.module.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.SystemSetup.roomticket',[])
        .config(config);

    /** @ngInject */
    function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider, msApiProvider, msNavigationServiceProvider) {
        // State
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.roomticket', {
                url: '/roomticket',
                views: {
                    'content@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/main/SystemSetup/RoomTicket/RoomTicket.html',
                        controller: 'RoomTicketController'
                    }
                },
                data: { requiresLogin: true },
                bodyClass: 'Room Ticket',
                ModuleName: 'Room Ticket'
            });  
    }
})();
```

Comment: make sure you're including the Roomticket.controller.js in your index.html

Comment: @SawantSharma I did but it was not injecting the  controller still so i had to add the controller functionality in my module itself.